# Problemas ao definir o layout

Tags: xml, android-layout

Não estou conseguindo fazer com que aceite esta definição de layout referente ao tamanho da Web View:

```
<RelativeLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
     android:layout_height="match_parent" 
     android:orientation="vertical" 
     android:paddingLeft="5dp" 
     android:paddingRight="5dp">
  <TextView 
      android:id="@+id/title" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
      android:text="@string/title" 
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
      android:textStyle="bold" /> 
 <ScrollView android:id="@+id/sv" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_below="@+id/title" 
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
 <RelativeLayout 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <WebView android:id="@+id/desc" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
      android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay" 
      android:text="@string/desc" /> 
  </RelativeLayout>
  </ScrollView>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Em todo o tag WebView sai esse erro:**Placing a  in a parent element that uses a wrap_content size can lead to subtle bugs; use match_parent.**

Answer (score 1):

Não sei muito bem o propósito, mas não é recomendado deixar seu `WebView` com tamanho limitado, a idéia é que ele sempre ocupe o máximo de tela possível, usando `layout_height="match_parent"`.

Como o próprio `WebView` já tem scroll, não precisa usar um `ScrollView` nele. Além disso dei uma simplificada no seu layout, ficando:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:text="@string/desc" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Tentei desse jeito, de outras maneiras, de preferência com o match_parent, mas ele continua assim, menor que o ideal:http://dc544.4shared.com/img/Bdb3mEvwba/s3/14958605688/device-2014-10-28-180801.png.

Comment: Vi que ele ocupou tudo menos o tamanho do título, não seria isso? Poderia marcar na imagem ou colocar um padding e usar um background para mostrar a borda do WebView?

Comment: vou ver aqui
pode ser isso mesmo